# Can anyone tell me why the following map is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, exact-sequence

There is a question and an answer on the following link:
[Question concerning a faithful module over an Artinian ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358703/question-concerning-a-faithful-module-over-an-artinian-ring)

But there is one place I can't understand in the answer of the question. That is :why this map $A \rightarrow \Pi _{i \in I} (Ax_i)$ given by $a \rightarrow (ax_i)_{i\in I}$ is injective? Can anyone tell me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is a part of the proof of the $\implies$ direction, and therefore it is being assumed that $M$ is a faithful module, i.e. that $\mathrm{Ann}_A(M)=0$. Also, note that $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ generates $M$.

Assume that for some $a\in A$, we have $ax_i=0$ for all $i\in I$. Then $am=0$ for all $m\in M$ since the $x_i$'s are a generating set, and thus $a\in\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$, hennce $a=0$. Therefore the map is injective.

Comment: You say that since the $x_i$'s are a generating set then $am=0$ for all $m \in M$. But I don't think so. For example, if N is a positive integer and $m= \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i m_i$, where $a_i \in A$, since we only have $ax_i=0$ for all $i \in I$, but we don't have that $a a_i x_i=0$, how dou you get $am=0$?